# update image properties

Tags: lua, corona-sdk

Is there a way to update the location of an image?

I'm currently calling my image dynamically using:

```
itemImage = display.newImage(inventory[t.ID][1])
```

t. being my target ID.

But in order for Storyboard to properly work, I need to change its location in my code to above my function, rendering its dynamic properties useless. Is there a way to update it like you can do with .text?

something along the lines of:

```
itemImage.image(inventory[t.ID][1])
itemImage.imageUpdate(inventory[t.ID][1])
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

No. You have two options.

Firstly, you can remove the image and then request the next one.

```
display.remove(itemImage)
itemImage = nil
local myOtherImage = display.newImageRect()
```

If you call the old image again later, this is fine as the images are cached by Corona.

Secondly, you can use an image sheet:

```
display.remove(imageItem)
itemImage = nil
local myOtherImage = display.newImageRect(imageSheet, frame, width, height)
```

This allows you to pull images from an efficiently packed image sheet.

I must admit I don't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish. There is no reason you should be struggling with this and storyboard. Perhaps post a few more details with the specific problem.

As a side note, you should try and use newImageRect as this allows for scaling:

http://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/api/library/display/newImageRect.html